# How to test if a certain text is displayed on the page

Tags: reactjs, laravel, testing, breeze

I have a question about testing Laravel + Breeze(React). I useually tested my Laravel's app via Http tests (Feature) but in this case it's not enaught. For example - depends of users role I want to display other content or opther options in menu, so into test I need to test text which is display. But this is react - Feature doesn't have an access to website content. OK. I can learn tools to test frontend framework but more problem is connecent backend and frontend. For example - in the Feature i can created example user with admin's role and into this same method I can test that this user can see some text. So, how you testing your Laravel + Breeze app?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/dusk there is a package for frontend testing

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cypress IO](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress) for writing E2E tests:

```
describe('Feature', () => {
  it('page should contain text', () => {
    cy.visit('/PAGE')

    cy.contains('text')
  })
})
```